# Using Sphinx to document multiple Python projects

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I've read a few Sphinx tutorials but I'm still a bit hung up on how I set up multiple projects.

What I mean is, after installing Sphinx, [this guide](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html) says

> To get started, cd into the documentation directory and type: `$ sphinx-quickstart`

Let's say I have 5 separate Python projects each in it's own directory (all individual git repos, etc).

**My question is, what exactly is *"the documentation directory"* (aside from the obvious) and how do I set up Sphinx when working with multiple projects?**

Do I make one "master documentation directory" somewhere and as I use Sphinx, do I create sub directories for each project or similar?

Or do I create a "documentation directory" inside of each of my projects and run `$ sphinx-quickstart` to set up Sphinx for each individual project?

I'm trying to understand the big picture here but can't find a tutorial that spells out this aspect of things.

Comment: What do you mean *"set up multiple projects"*. If they're separate, in separate directories, then of course you will have to `-quickstart` each one. Or are you trying to combine them somehow?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's what I figured but I just wasnt sure. To me, the tutorials dont make it clear where the *the documentation directory* should be. I wasnt sure if Sphinx expects this folder to be like a central repo for all my documentation or if `sphinx-quickstart` was intended to be run on a per project basis like `git init` etc. Seems your answer is the later per project setup. Is it advised to create the documentation directory in my Python project or outside of it?

Comment: It reads *"documentation directory"* because the directory name and relative position in the project directory is up to you. I usually put it in `project_root/docs` per http://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/. Looking at the link you posted, they seem to use `doc` instead.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for your time, and pointing me to that awesome blog post! If you feel like throwing an answer, Ill accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sphinx-quickstart` command generates a documentation skeleton for *a single project*, so if you have multiple separate projects you will have to run it in each one of them. The link you posted uses the phrase *"documentation directory"* because the directory name and relative position in the project directory is up to you (they appear to be putting it in `project_root/doc`), not because there should be some centralised directory of documentation for all of your projects.